# Reusable uiscrollview class

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, subclass

I frequently need to display a uiscrollview with an image within that you can zoom. This is on top of the many other scrollviews I am using in any particular app.

I'd like to break this out into its own class that I could instantiate kind of like:

```
CustomScrollView *scr = [CustomScrollView alloc] init];
scr.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
scr.doesPinchZoom = YES;
```

CustomScrollView should create a uiscrollview with an image inside that allows pinching and zooming.

This would have its own close button as well to remove said scrollview.
My code right now cannot even create a scrollview.

```
@interface CustomScrollView () <UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIScrollView *scrollView;
@end

@implementation CustomScrollView

@synthesize scrollView = _scrollView;

- (UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (nil == _scrollView) {
        _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _scrollView.delegate = self;
        [_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self addSubview:_scrollView];
        NSLog(@"scrollview");
    }
    return _scrollView;
}
```

Any direction on going down this road? Or even just getting the scrollview to show up...
The scrollview does not even show up in my view controller when I instantiate it using the above alloc.

Comment: You haven't described what goes wrong with the code you have.  Please edit your post to describe the result you are seeing.  Also explain what a `ebZoomingScrollView` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the code you posted is supposed to be a combination of your .h/.m files, but regardless I believe, unless I'm misunderstanding you, that you're trying to make a subclass of a UIScrollView object. You can definitely do this to customize a UIScrollView and make it reusable in many situations.

If you name your subclass CustomScrollView an example header file would look like:

```
//
//  CustomScrollView.h
//


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomScrollView : UIScrollView

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *theImage;

@end
```

And your implementation file:

```
//
//  CustomScrollView.m


#import "CustomScrollView.h"

@implementation CustomScrollView

@synthesize theImage;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        theImage = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setTheImage:(UIImageView*)image{


    theImage = image;
    [self addSubview:theImage];

}

@end
```

And then wherever you want to use your new Custom ScrollView for ex you could do:

```
CustomScrollView *cSV = [[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
cSV.delegate = self;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourPic.png"];
[cSV setTheImage:imageView];
[self.view addSubview:cSV];
```

(I did random frames you could set them to what you want)

From there you could create class methods to do the other things you want to do

Hopefully this is helpful in some way